# Override self.friendly_token in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In `devise/lib/devise.rb` there is a method called `self.friendly_token`:

```
def self.friendly_token(length = 20)
  # To calculate real characters, we must perform this operation.
  # See SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  rlength = (length * 3) / 4
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(rlength).tr('lIO0', 'sxyz')
end
```

I want to change `.tr('lIO0', 'sxyz')` to `.tr('lIO0-', 'sxyz')` and override it in my application, and there the problems starts. I do not know how to do it. Can anybody help me with that? I am using Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put this code in the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file:

```
module Devise
  def self.friendly_token(length = 20)
    # your implementation
  end
end
```

It doesn't matter which file in the `config/initializers/` folder you will put this code into. Maybe a better solution would be to add a new file named like this `config/initializers/devise_overrides.rb` and place the code there.

Comment: Work fine. I thought it will be more complicated. I should try first before asking. Thank you very much.